# "Recap"-equivalent Japanese word

Tags: word-requests

Can somebody please tell me an equivalent word to say "recap" in Japanese ? I want to express the following in Japanese:

> Let me recap the results we discussed in the last presentation

If necessary, the 'last presentation' is an event that took place in past. How do I say this in Japanese ?

I looked it up in weblio translator site which showed 要約 which I don't feel as appropriate for this situation.

I found the following answer when I searched recap in this site: [Meaning of 様子を交える](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29739/meaning-of-%E6%A7%98%E5%AD%90%E3%82%92%E4%BA%A4%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B/30263#30263)

I dont think 総括 is used to mean  recap. Native Japanese mostly use it to mean "generalize" .

Please help.

Comment: why do you think `要約` is not appropriate? Going by [Eijiro](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%e8%a6%81%e7%b4%84&ref=sa) it seems fitting to me.

Comment: 要約 is not too bad, but it tends to refer to something you read *before* (or *without*) reading the main content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phrases I would recommend are:

・（簡単{かんたん}に）要点{ようてん}をおさらいする

・（簡単に）要点をまとめる

・ 概要{がいよう}を繰{く}り返{かえ}す

If you are speaking instead of writing, I would especially recommend the first two.